# mpirun kill parallel processes when lose internet connection ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, kill, mpi

When I'm connected via ssh and are parallel processes running and it loses the internet connection all parallel processes. When I reconnect I find the following message in log file:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 12 in communicator MPI COMMUNICATOR 4 DUP FROM 0 
with errorcode 15.

NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.
You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on
exactly when Open MPI kills them.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
0:Terminate signal was sent, status=: 15
(rank:0 hostname: pid:2953):ARMCI DASSERT fail. ../../ga-5-4/armci/src/common/signaltrap.c:SigTermHandler():477 cond:0
```

Distribution

> Description:          Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Release:
> 16.04 Codename:       xenial

How can I prevent this crash?

Comment: Perhaps run the process on the remote system under a `tmux` or `screen` session?

Answer (score 0):

tmux is the solution here. the problem is that when the ssh connection closes it ends whatever bash session you were running. to solve this just type `tmux` and then type run the start running your program. you can then hit ctrl + b and then d to exit. this will leave your code running in a separate bash session and when you close ssh it will continue to run. you can run `ssh user@ip ps a` with user and ip replaced with the real ones, to see if the process is still running after you close the connection

Comment: Sadly neither tmux nor screener are installed on the server.

Comment: is there a reason you cannot install them?

Comment: I'm not have root privilegies. IT support is not available for the next couple of weeks. :(